# How to resume screen?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

Let's say I have many screens open, and I would like to resume to a particular screen session using 'screen -r ' 
this is wahat i get when I execute screen -r 
There are several suitable screens on:

```
12670.pts-8.b-dev03 (Detached)
23662.pts-9.b-dev03 (Detached)
502.pts-1.b-dev03   (Attached)
19972.pts-1.b-dev03 (Detached)
9414.pts-24.b-dev03 (Attached)
16607.pts-1.p-dev03 (Detached)
3015.pts-2.b-dev03  (Detached)
14313.pts-18.b-dev03    (Attached) 
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
```

How  do I resume one of them, lets say the last one which is attached.
I have tried -

```
screen -r 14313.pts-18.b-dev03
 There is a screen on:
14313.pts-18.b-dev03    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 14313.pts-18.b-dev03.
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The wording is a little unlucky - this happens because there still is a `screen` session attached to `14313.pts-18.b-dev03` and you cannot simply "resume" a non-detached session. You need to use the `-x` option in addition to attaching to this session with a second `screen` instance (or, alternatively, detach the existing session first):

> -x
>
> ```
>   Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode).
> ```

```
$ screen -xr 14313
```

If you wish to detach the first session instead:

> -d -r
>
> ```
>   Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.
> ```

```
$ screen -dr 14313
```

Comment: What will happen to my previous instance of the non-detached screen? I actually want the previous session to be resumed, so that I can see the progress

Comment: In multi display mode both sessions are active and have write access (so you can interact with both instances and see the ouput in all connected instances) unless you make the session read-only (then the second instance can only watch). So you can continue with `-xr` as normal, and if you detach with the second instance the first instance will remain there and stay attached. But you can detach the first session if you wish by using `-dr` (see the manpage).